# Capture an event when someone connects with ipad/iphone on Mac/Pc?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I want to capture an event when a user connects iPad to Mac.
I didn't found any library or framework.

Any solution?

Comment: You may need to start with few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Connects in what way?

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the device is charging:

```
UIDeviceBatteryState batState = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryState;
if (batState == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging) {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you must enable batteryStatus notification (in appDelegate.m for instance):

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    ...
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
    // Now, the system will post UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification notification when batteryStatus (or connection) will change

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryStatusDidChange:) name:UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

// Now, your app will receive UIDeviceBatteryStatusDidChange notification in batteryStatusDidChange: method
        ...
    }

Then, you can receive battery status change notification in your define method:

```
- (void)batteryStatusDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    ...
    NSString *str = @"???";

    switch( [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryState )
    {
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown :
            str = @"Unknown";
            break;
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged :
            str = @"Unplugged";
            / adjust global screen max brightness
            [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 0.9;
            break;
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging :
            str = @"Charging";
            [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 1.0;
            break;
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateFull :
            str = @"Full";
            break;
    }
    ...
}
```